# Factor the polynomial $x^{15}+3x^{10}+2x^5+4$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$.

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, factoring

Factor the polynomial $f(x)=x^{15}+3x^{10}+2x^5+4$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$.

Alright, so I'm sure this is a simple answer but I have not been able to figure out, hopefully I can quickly be set on the right track.

Typically to do this I would find $f'(x)$, then $\gcd(f,f')$ and proceed from there vis-a-vis the Square-Free method of factoring polynomials over finite fields.

However, $f'(x)=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$. I did not see any reference to this case in my textbook, but I did find the following explanation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields), which seems like it should be useful here:

> [The Square-free] algorithm uses the fact that, if the derivative of a polynomial is zero, then it is a polynomial in $x^p$, which is, if the coefficients belong to $\mathbb{F}_p$, the $p^{th}$ power of the polynomial obtained by substituting $x$ by $x^{1/p}$.

What is meant here by substituting $x$ by $x^{1/p}$?

My first thought was to substitute each term in the polynomial, e.g. $x^{15} \rightarrow \left(x^{15}\right)^{1/5}=x^3$. But I don't know how that substitution would apply to $4$, since $4^{1/5}$ doesn't make much sense in $\mathbb{F}_5$.

Comment: Just try it out! If you take that polynomial to the 5th power, you get exactly your polynomial back.  You don't need to do anything with the 4, because $4^5=1024$, which is 4 mod 5.

Comment: What you've written at the end of your question is not how substitution works. If you substitute $x^{1/5}$ for $x$ in the term $x^{15}$ you will get $(x^{1/5})^{15} = x^3$. Similarly, with the term $4$, there's no $x$ here so the term stays the same. Alternatively you could write it as $4x^0 = 4(x^{1/5})^0 = 4 x^0$ and it still stays the same if that helps. Really there's nothing special happening here, you could just as well make this substitution for a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ that you'd find in a high school algebra class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the polynomial
$$
4+2 \left(x^{1/5}\right)^5+3 \left(x^{1/5}\right)^{10}+\left(x^{1/5}\right)^{15}
=x^3+3 x^2+2 x+4\,
$$
In a field of characteristic $p$, we have that
$$
(a+b)^p = a^p +b^p\,,
$$
so that, by a quick finite induction argument,
$$
(x^3+3 x^2+2 x+4)^5
=
\left(x^3\right)^5 + \left(3x^2\right)^5 + \left(2x\right)^5 + 4^5
=
x^{15}+3^5x^{10}+2^5x^5+4^5x^5\,
$$
which reduces to the original polynomial by Fermat's little theorem.

---

If we had forgotten about the above rule (like me, earlier), we can just compute the fifth power of this polynomial using *Mathematica*, yielding
$$
x^{15}+15 x^{14}+100 x^{13}+410 x^{12}+1225 x^{11}+2923 x^{10}+5730 x^9+9420 x^8+13280 x^7+15920 x^6+16352 x^5+14400
   x^4+10240 x^3+6400 x^2+2560 x+1024\,
$$
which can be seen to reduce to
$$
x^{15}+3 x^{10}+2 x^5+4
$$
mod 5.

Comment: You can use equality $f^p+g^p=(f+g)^p$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

Comment: @richrow.  Thanks! Of course! Will edit.